# background color not changing in python in OS X

Tags: python

i typed the below code in my sublime text, but as this code is used by people to change the background color; i hope it would happen, but, unfortunately it didn't. i.e precisely color didn't change. i
then i started to research in stackoverflow.
some questions like this in (mac os ) has been already asked. 
though, you people say that that question will answer my question, it does to some level; but I would love to get the answer of this question. [Why does my Tkinter window background not change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47301571/why-does-my-tkinter-window-background-not-change)
likewise a similar question was asked, like this; [Python tkinter window background/canvas not changing colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570113/python-tkinter-window-background-canvas-not-changing-colour)

```
import sys
import pygame
def run_game():
    #initialize game and create a screen object.
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    #set the background color.
    bg_color=pygame.color.Color('#FFFFF')
    # start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        #watch for keyboard and mouse events.

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
              sys.exit()
              #redraw the sceen during each pass through the loop
              screen.fill(bg_color)
              #make most recently drawn screen visible
              pygame.display.flip()

run_game
```

Comment: how to correct this code, though it seems logically correct!

Comment: You need to call the function, try add a `()` after `run_game`

Comment: it shows indentation error after doing that () in run_game.

Comment: that suggested program isn't working for me! how can I just change sth in this code, and get output. can I?